# Store text as string vs. bytes

Tags: anchor, solana-program, account, account-data

Is there any advantage to using `Vec<u8>` over `String` to store text in storage account fields? And if so, why? From [a storage perspective](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/space.html), they are nearly handled identically as far as I can tell from the docs.

Comment: Like the answers below already mention, there's no advantage since both are represented very similarly. Using an array on the other hand costs 4 bytes less than either of a vec or string.

Answer (score 2):

A fixed-size u8 array is often preferable to allow you to predict the size of struct.

Between `Vec` and `String` there's not much difference, but it can be easier to work with bytes when passing the args on the front end (e.g., use `someString.toBuffer()` with the preferred encoding vs figuring out if the text is UTF8/16/32). Your Rust strings default to UTF8 and your JS strings are UTF16, though this is rarely a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any advantage, the size would be the same and you would need to make the serialization and deserialization from `String` to `u8` yourself so using `String` would we more easy